# Anti-pollution warning light Peuguot 308

Tags: peugeot

I have a Peugeot 308 2009 five door hatch back - 1.4 petrol.

The anti-pollution warning light comes up to indicate a fault every time I start the car, but i've taken the car to a mechanic and he says there is nothing wrong, but the issue arises because i don't drive the car often. He said he can replace the filter for me, but that will cost around £200 to order.
I recall reading that the warning light may go off if i take the car on the motorway, but i drove almost 2 hours on the motorway a couple of days later, and the warning light was still there.

It's been about a month since then and my car is running just fine, but I was just curious whether you guys would recommend that I replace the filter?

Thanks!

Comment: Which filter are you talking about? What are the codes which come up?